# Angular animation events (start/done) not firing

Tags: angular

I'm trying, in my angular app, to get notified about the start and end of an angular animation (described [here](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationEvent))

So I created a very basic staggering [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pintwg?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2Fcomponents.module.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2Flist%2Flist.component.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2Flist%2Flist.component.html,src%2Fcomponents%2Flist%2Flist.component.scss,src%2Fcomponents%2Flist-item%2Flist-item.component.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2Flist-item%2Flist-item.component.html,src%2Fcomponents%2Flist-item%2Flist-item.component.scss)

```
animations: [
trigger('stagger', [
  transition(':enter', [
    query(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      stagger('300ms', [animate('500ms', style({ opacity: 1 }))]),
    ]),
  ]),
]),
```

],

and the html/implementation

```
<ol class="flow">
    <li *ngFor="let context of data">
        <ol class="context" [@stagger]>
            <li *ngFor="let item of context.items">
                <app-list-item
                   [data]="item"
                  (@stagger.start)="endAnimation(item)"
                  (@stagger.done)="endAnimation(item)"
                ></app-list-item>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Although the animation is working, the callbacks are not fired. Any suggestions what might be the problem with my code?

Comment: Shouldn't the event bindings be on the `<ol>`? [Example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/alert/src/alert/alert.component.html#L1)

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thanks a lot!